# Closure on sets under (W,+)

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Is a set of multiples of 6 closed under Whole numbers addition?

I think, yes. If I add any two elements of the set, I will always get a multiple of 6.
Is my reasoning correct? Will be closed for any set of multiples? It is confusing for me with infinite sets. Thanks

Comment: Let $m=6k$ and $n=6k'$ where $k,k'\in W$. Then $m+n=6(k+k')$

Comment: Thanks, so is closed? I'm confused as 0 is in W, and is not a multiple of 6. Can you please explain?

Comment: It is closed as you might think!

Comment: In fact $0=6 \cdot 0$ is a multiple of $6$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now.